# Demonstrating colour theory through these exercises

Tags: color, theory

Can you please explain how I'm supposed to create these tasks?

• Using coloured paper swatches, give examples of the following 3 Colour Chords: dyad,triad and tetrad.

• Using paint or paper, create 3 examples of colour contrast. Choose 3 from the following
list and illustrate each one in a 3x3 grid. Write a brief description identifying the contrast
presented, as well as how they successfully achieves the effect.
» Contrast of hue
» Contrast of extension
» Contrast of light and dark
» Contrast of saturation
» Contrast of warm/ cold
» Complementary contrast
» Simultaneous contrast

Comment: We're not here to do your homework for you, sorry. Presumably whoever set the task either knew they had already taught you how to do it, or were expecting you to do your own research, as opposed to just asking others to do it for you.

Comment: These terms are all googleable.

Comment: Hi Sally, Welcome to Graphic Design. Please explain what you mean by "how … to create these tasks" in greater detail. You should ask your instructor about specific submission guidelines such as format.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to take a bit of pity here and explain what you're supposed to be thinking about and learning and demonstrating here, all without doing any work for you.

This is under the presumption that you genuinely feel lost and confused about the assignment, and further that you're not simply trying to get us to do your homework for you!

---

**General background:**

In colour theory, there are a number of different conceptual approachs to making colour harmonies, and the resulting sets of colour swatches you create when applying them are often referred to as colour chords.

For example, complementary colours are those at direct opposite on a typical colour wheel - those whose hue angles are literally 180 degrees apart. They have the highest possible chromatic contrast.

**Your work:**
In one or more of your course materials, your professor or design department has published their terminology for specific types of colour harmonies and chords, and they want you to exemplify these, by you choosing an initial hue, and then applying the given harmony type to get the other hues needed to make up the chord.

Further they wish you to demonstrate that you understand the material they've taught and introduced differentiating between hue angle (the specific colour), tone or value (relative darkness) saturation (the strength of chroma independent of its hue) and warmth / coldness (generic blue/greenness vs red/yellowness) and to demonstrate that understanding by setting up a matrix in which you compare two extremes in each of these axis, with an in-between swatch showing the midpoint of the given gradient, and that you do this in a 3 x 3 matrix - so you can clearly demonstrate knowing the difference between say choma / saturation and hue angle, or between value and chroma.

---

I remember with some fondness doing these sorts of exercises when I studied art and graphic design, and then again, years later, when I studied architecture I encountered it all again, from a slightly different perspective.

Hope this helps - but only enough to get you moving forwards on your own!